# Defining new column type based on X

Tags: tabularx

When I have few paragraph cells in my tables, the cells are not vertically centered. To fix this, I have the following minimal document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mX}[1]{\parbox[c]{\hsize}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|X|}\hline
Test 1&
\mX{\lipsum[1]}
&Test 2&\mX{\lipsum[1-2]}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I was wondering if instead doing this, I can define a new column, say `mX` such that the following document would produce exactly the same output as the top one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{mX}{...}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|mX|c|mX|}\hline
Test 1&
\lipsum[1]
&Test 2&\lipsum[1-2]
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

That is I do not want to use the additional command `\mX` or even use additional commands like `\mX` or `\multicolumn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine locally the `X` column type. I took the opportunity to add some padding to your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
{\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|X|}\hline
Test 1&
\lipsum[1]
&Test 2&\lipsum[1-2]
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

[image]